# Possible Minor Error in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, fourier-transform

**Relevant Passage**

I am currently reading Chapter 9 in the third edition of W. Rudin's 'Real and Complex Analysis'. On page 184 Rudin writes:

"On account of 9.7(4) we have
\begin{align}
(g*h_\lambda)(x)-g(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty[g(x-y)-g(x)]h_\lambda(y)\ dm(y) \\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty[g(x-y)-g(x)]\lambda^{-1}h_1\left(\frac{y}{\lambda}\right)\ dm(y) \\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty[g(x-\lambda s)-g(x)]h_1(s)\ dm(s).
\end{align}
The last integrand is dominated by $2||g||_\infty h_1(s)$ and converges to 0 pointwise for every $s$ as $\lambda\rightarrow0$. Hence (1) follows from the dominated convergence theorem."

**Context**

The definition given for $h_\lambda(x)$ is:
$$
h_\lambda(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itx-\lambda|t|}\ dm(t)\qquad(\lambda>0),\ x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
9.7(3) and 9.7(4) state
$$
h_\lambda(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2+x^2},\qquad \int_{-\infty}^\infty h_\lambda(x)\ dm(x)=1.
$$
respectively, where $\lambda>0$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and $dm(x)$ represents Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ divided by $\sqrt{2\pi}$. Also, (1) states
$$
\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow0}(g\star h_\lambda)(x)=g(x)
$$

**The Error[s]**

I believe 9.7(4) clearly should be replaced with 9.7(3) in the above passage, and that 9.7(4) should instead be invoked to justify use of the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

It is difficult to find errata for this well written classic, so I thought I might confirm that this is indeed an error on Math SA.

Comment: I believe the textbook is correct: You're using 9.7(4) to get the very first equality in the display, the computation in general doesn't involve the particular definition of $h$ at all.

Comment: Are you wanting to reference 9.7(3) to relate $h_\lambda$ and $h_1$?

Comment: @Jose27 Okay I see that now, but doesn't the second line follow from 9.7(3)?

Comment: I don't have access to that text, but I would assume it defines $h_\lambda$ somewhere.  What does it give as a definition?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I added the definition to my post

Comment: In a sense, yes you use 9.7(3) for that, but notice that all you really need is that $h_\lambda(x)= \lambda^{-1}h_1(x/\lambda)$ and $\int h_1(x)=1$ for the argument to work.